# Mailchimp rest api

Tags: rest, mailchimp

I've started working with MailChimp's api.
I've tried connecting to their servers using a rest call 
based on a sample code I've found somewhere:

http://api.mailchimp.com/1.3/?output=json&method=campaignTemplateContent&apikey=**MyKey-us2**&cid=**myId**

Unfortounatly I keep getting this error:

```
{"error":"Invalid Mailchimp API Key: **MyKey**-us2 . You are accessing the wrong datacenter - your client library may not properly support our datacenter mapping scheme.","code":104}
```

I can't find any other code samples working on MailChimp's rest api.
What am I doing wrong here? Where are the code samples?

Thanks

Comment: if you solved the error kindly give me solution too? here is my problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787248/invalid-api-key-while-creating-new-campaign-using-mailchimp-in-asp-net

Comment: I'm sorry it's been quite some time ago, I not longer remember the issue nor the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. You should be hitting http://us2.api.mailchimp.com instead of the one you're using.